# GWT CellTable. Text along row

Tags: java, gwt

Gwt CellTable can show only objects. But I need to generate columns dynamically (so I can't predefine all fields in my class that require CellTable); and make some rows as "headers"  Like this:

[image]

Or may be you can advice me some other solution.  (Table can have up to 2000 rows. So also I need paging)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, is your data object fixed or it is dynamically retrieved at runtime? Which is the driving point (UI or Data) in your case?

Comment: @questzen,  Columns and their data dynamically retrieved at runtime. Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Celltable requires you to define each row separately anyway. If you look at the Showcae code, you see, that each Column is added like this:

```
Column<YOURDATAOBJECT, String> nameColumn = new Column<YOURDATAOBJECT, String>(
        new TextCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(YOURDATAOBJECT object) {
        return object.getYOURCOLUMDATA();
    }
};
this.addColumn(nameColumn, YOURHEADERNAME);
```

So it is possible to add the columns as simply as that as at any point of your code, as long as the data is in your DataProvider you defined for you CellTable. So you question doesn't concern the CellTable, it concerns the DataProvider you defined for you CellTable.

CellTable supports paging via the [SimplePager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.html).

**All in all CellTable supports both features you need, but it takes some time to understand them.**

In case You haven't seen it, take a look at the official Google ShowCase for CellTable

- [CellTable](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)
- [Data Grid](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid)
- [Cell Sample](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSamplerData)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how to add new columns if i don't have predefined POJO class? this code     `@Override
    public String getValue(YOURDATAOBJECT object) {
        return object.getYOURCOLUMDATA();
    }  get value ` get value from predefined field of class YOURDATAOBJECT. But I haven't this POJO, because my columns always dynamical, I don't know how many columns i receive from DB.  

 What about "Header1" and "Header2" lines? Since cellTable require POJO object, how i can display this rows\?

Comment: Did you already take a look at the ListDataProvider? (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html )

Comment: YOURDATAOBJEC...Yes, I used it in last project... But WHAT I WILL WRITE INSTEAD  `String getValue(YOURDATAOBJECT object)` I Haven't PREDEFINED class YOURDATAOBJEC. I can't it create, because i can't predict how many columns I need to display!

Comment: You can define that class to have any number of rows. For your cells you just have to have a method to recive this rows uniquly. So you can define a method in your POJO like getItem(String name) {...} and in you Column you write "return object.getname("Item1");". This whay your POJO can have any number of RowEntries and they can be changed dynamically at runtime!

Comment: ok ,thanks, But again i ask about making "Header1" and "Header2" lines. How to make them?

Comment: You'll have to wait for GWT 2.5 (or build GWT from trunk) and use the `CellTableBuilder`; see http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid for a live sample.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer what about `CellTableBuilder`? It not included to 2.5 release. Is stable? Can I use it?

Comment: It's there in GWT 2.5: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTableBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently as far as I know the gwt celltable can't do the header rows like you want.  I believe the GXT grid controls can though.

http://www.sencha.com/examples/